# How to let the process just die when child activity throws an uncaught exception

Tags: android

Activity `A` starts a child activity `B`, if `B` fails with an uncaught exception, it closes and Android system starts the parent activity `A` in a new process. Now, everything would be fine if that parent activity starts with a fresh state but it doesn't. The state of the activity is restored somehow even though it's a new process. This causes a whole lot of problems.

Reading similar questions, this is what I've tried so far:

**In child activity:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandle() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            // replacing the following 5 with just finish() doesn't help
            // either because then the screen just goes all black
            final Intent rootActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RootActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(rootActivity);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(0);
            return;
        }
    };
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Other thing I tried is setting `android:multiProcess="false"` for the parent activity...doesn't change anything.

Android system still starts the parent activity (in a new process) and executes onRestoreInstance.

I would like the application to die completely with an "Unexpected error occured" or whatever system dialog and not restart at all.

Please help, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and nicer for the user) if you handled those exceptions better?

Comment: @323go: we are talking about the uncaught ones here...of course, I will have exception handlers for most of the possibilities I can think of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could kind of emulate this behavior by Yourself. Start Activity B with `startActivityForResult` and in Activity B just set `setResult(RESULT_CANCELLED);`. If your Activity has an uncought exception, you should recieve `onActivityResult`. If that Result is still cancelled, you could just finish your Activity and start a new one with an Intent. You just have to set another Result in Activity B if it was successful before finishing it!